# Добавить строку в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html

как добавить еще 1 строку в таблицу по нажатию кнопки

```html
<div class="data-list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте обработчик onClick к вашей кнопке.

```js
$(".btn-add").click(function() {
  $(this.parentElement).find("table tbody").append("<tr><td>...</td></tr>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data-list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

так? только перегружается страница и ничего нет

```
$(".btn-add").click(function() {
  $(this.parentElement).find("table tbody").append('<tr class="data-row">
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb[]" value="25"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch[]"></td>
                  <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems[]"></td>
                </tr>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var dataRow = document.getElementsByClassName('data-row')[0];
var btnAdd = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-add')[0];

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var line = dataRow.cloneNode(true);
  tBody.appendChild(line)
})
```

```html
<div class="data-list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```